# Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP: "Firebase" is not defined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting this error "Firebase is not defined", when using "Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP" to set the current firebase server time.
This is probably the old way. Any idea about how to do that with the new Firebase?
Thank you!

Comment: Without seeing the problematic code it's hard to say more than that your import it likely wrong. The documentation for `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps

Comment: Frank, thanks a lot! I couldn't find the new documentation for the server timestamp. I was so used to the old one. Now learning the new doc :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue, with firebase 3.1, the syntax is :

```
firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```